# split filename in loop and reference each part

Tags: mysql, debian, bash

I have a directory with a list of files in it, e.g.

```
file.name.aaaaaa.111111
file.name.bbbbbb.222222
file.name.cccccc.333333
```

I need a way to take each file, split it at the "." and then using each section it will be passed to a mysql query.

I have the following:

```
for file in $localdir/file.name.*
do
    filename=`basename "$file"`
    for i in $(echo $filename | tr "." "\n")
    do
        echo $i
    done
done
```

How can I refer to the individual parts? as I only need 'aaaaa' and '11111' for the MySQL query?

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual names of the files.

Comment: sorry, I was just trying to keep it simple to avoid getting into what all the different parts mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just `aaaaaa` using `cut` with `.` being used as the delimiter:

```
echo $filename | cut -f 3 -d '.'
```

To get just `111111`, just change the field number:

```
echo $filename | cut -f 4 -d '.'
```

To get the whole second portion, you can use Bash's inbuilt string manipulation:

```
echo ${filename#*.name.}
```

Comment: that's great cheers, and does exactly what I need.